# Service Socket Disconnect on Background->Foreground switch

Tags: java, android, sockets, service

I am writing an IRC Client.  The socket connection to the IRC Server is handled via a service.  I have managed to stabilize all the UI elements of the Activities in question during the orientation change, but somehow the socket that is maintained by the service is being closed during the change.

Here is what I believe to be the relevant code.  Please let me know if you need to see more.

```
//This is the Service in question
public class ConnectionService extends Service{

private BlockingQueue<String> MessageQueue;

public final IBinder myBind = new ConnectionBinder();

public class ConnectionBinder extends Binder {
    ConnectionService getService() {
        return ConnectionService.this;
    }
}

private Socket socket;
private BufferedWriter writer;
private BufferedReader reader;

private IRCServer server;

private WifiManager.WifiLock wLock; 

private Thread readThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine( )) != null) {
                if (line.toUpperCase().startsWith("PING ")) {
                    SendMessage("PONG " + line.substring(5));
                }
                else
                    queueMessage(line);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }

});

@Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    if(MessageQueue == null)
        MessageQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();

    return Service.START_STICKY;
  }

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return myBind;
}

@Override
public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
    try {
        socket.close();
        wLock.release();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return super.stopService(name);
}

    @Override
public void onDestroy()
{//I put this here so I had a breakpoint in place to make sure this wasn't firing instead of stopService
    try {
        socket.close();
        wLock.release();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    super.onDestroy();
}

public void SendMessage(String message)
{
    try {
        writer.write(message + "\r\n");
        writer.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String readLine()
{
    try {
        if(!isConnected())
            return null;
        else
            return MessageQueue.take();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return "";
    }
}

public boolean ConnectToServer(IRCServer newServer)
{
    try {
        //create a new message queue (connecting to a new server)
        MessageQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();

        //lock the wifi
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wLock = wifiManager.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "LockTag");
        wLock.acquire();

        server = newServer;

        //connect to server
        socket = new Socket();
        socket.setKeepAlive(true);
        socket.setSoTimeout(60000);

        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(server.NAME, Integer.parseInt(server.PORT)), 10000);

        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        //run basic login scripts.
        if(server.PASS != "")
            SendMessage("PASS " + server.PASS);

        //write nickname
        SendMessage("NICK " + server.NICK);

        //write username login
        SendMessage("USER " + server.NICK + " 0 * :Fluffy IRC");

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine( )) != null) {
            if (line.indexOf("004") >= 0) {
                // We are now logged in.
                break;
            }
            else if (line.indexOf("433") >= 0) {
                //change to alt Nick
                if(!server.NICK.equals(server.ALT_NICK) && !server.ALT_NICK.equals(""))
                {
                    server.NICK = server.ALT_NICK;
                    SendMessage("NICK " + server.NICK);
                }
                else
                {
                    queueMessage("Nickname already in use");
                    socket.close();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if (line.toUpperCase().startsWith("PING ")) {
                SendMessage("PONG " + line.substring(5));
            }
            else
            {
                queueMessage(line);
            }
        }

        //start the reader thread AFTER the primary login!!!
        CheckStartReader();

        if(server.START_CHANNEL == null || server.START_CHANNEL == "")
        {
            server.WriteCommand("/join " + server.START_CHANNEL);
        }
        //we're done here, go home everyone
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}

private void queueMessage(String line) {
    try {
        MessageQueue.put(line);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}

public boolean isConnected()
{
    return socket.isConnected();
}

public void CheckStartReader()
{
    if(this.isConnected() && !readThread.isAlive())
        readThread.start();
}
}

//Here are the relevant portions of the hosting Activity that connects to the service
//NOTE: THE FOLLOWING CODE IS PART OF THE ACTIVITY, NOT THE SERVICE
private ConnectionService conn;

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        conn = ((ConnectionService.ConnectionBinder)service).getService();
        Toast.makeText(main_tab_page.this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
          .show();
        synchronized (_serviceConnWait) {
            _serviceConnWait.notify();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        conn = null;
    }
  };

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
    state.putParcelable("Server", server);
    state.putString("Window", CurrentTabWindow.GetName());

    unbindService(mConnection);
}

        @Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    if(this.isFinishing())
        stopService(new Intent(this, ConnectionService.class));
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_tab_page);

    localTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHostMain);
    localTabHost.setup();
    localTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new tabChange());

    _serviceConnWait = new Object();

    if(savedInstanceState == null)
    {//initial startup, coming from Intent to start
        //get server definition
        server = (IRCServer)this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra(IRC_WINDOW);
        server.addObserver(this);
        AddTabView(server);

            startService(new Intent(this, ConnectionService.class));
    }
    else
    {
        server = (IRCServer)savedInstanceState.getParcelable("Server");
        String windowName = savedInstanceState.getString("Window");

        //Add Needed Tabs
        //Server
        if(!(windowName.equals(server.GetName())))
            AddTabView(server);
        //channels
        for(IRCChannel c : server.GetAllChannels())
            if(!(windowName.equals(c.GetName())))
                AddTabView(c);
        //reset each view's text (handled by tabChange)

        if(windowName.equals(server.GetName()))
            SetCurrentTab(server.NAME);
        else
            SetCurrentTab(windowName);

        ResetMainView(CurrentTabWindow.GetWindowTextSpan());

        //Rebind to service
        BindToService(new Intent(this, ConnectionService.class));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    final Intent ServiceIntent = new Intent(this, ConnectionService.class);

    //check start connection service
    final Thread serverConnect = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if(!BindToService(ServiceIntent))
                return;

            server.conn = conn;
            conn.ConnectToServer(server);
            server.StartReader();

            if(server.START_CHANNEL != null && !server.START_CHANNEL.equals(""))
            {
                IRCChannel chan = server.FindChannel(server.START_CHANNEL);

                if(chan != null)
                {
                    AddTabView(chan);
                }
                else
                {
                    server.JoinChannel(server.START_CHANNEL);
                    chan = server.FindChannel(server.START_CHANNEL);
                    AddTabView(chan);
                }

            }
        }

    });

    serverConnect.start();
}

private boolean BindToService(Intent ServiceIntent)
{
    int tryCount = 0;
    bindService(ServiceIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    while(conn == null && tryCount < 10)
    {
        tryCount++;
        try {
            synchronized (_serviceConnWait) {
                _serviceConnWait.wait(1500);
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //do nothing
        }
    }

    return conn != null;
}
```

Im not entirely certain what I am doing wrong there.  Obviously there's something I'm missing, haven't found yet, or haven't even thought to check.  What happens though is that after the orientation change my Send command gives me this message and nothing happens:

```
06-04 22:02:27.637: W/System.err(1024): java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
06-04 22:02:27.982: W/System.err(1024): at com.fluffyirc.ConnectionService.SendMessage(ConnectionService.java:90)
```

I have no idea when the socket is getting closed, or why.

**Update**

I have changed the code so that rather than binding to the service and using that to start it, instead I call `startService` and `stopService` at appropriate points as well as binding to it, on the thought that the service was being destroyed when the binding was lost.  This is working exactly like it was before I changed it.  The socket still closes on an orientation change, and I have no idea why.

**Update :- Code and description**

I added the code changes recently made for Start/Stop service and START_STICKY.  I also recently read a very good article explaining how the orientation change process flow works and why its NOT a bad idea to add the `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` line to your manifest. So this fixed the orientation issue, but its still doing the same thing if I put the activity into background mode, and then bring it back to the foreground.  That still follows the same Save/Destroy/Create process that the orientation does without that manifest line...and it still closes my socket, and I still don't know why.

I do know that it doesn't close the socket until the re-create process...I know this because the message queue will display messages that were received while the app was in the background, but once I bring it back forward it closes the socket and nothing else can be sent or received.

Comment: How are you starting your service?  You need to start it via an intent and return START_STICKY.

Comment: What is the Difference between returning START_NOT_STICKY and START_STICKY from the OnStartCommand override?  I am starting it via intent....Should I be saving that specific intent and re-using it after the orientation change to re-bind the service?

Comment: your service will be destroyed and recreated through the unbind/bind cycle unless you also start it with an Intent and return `START_STICKY`

Comment: hmm.  Didn't know that.  Thanks.  Although, I did change the code to do that (will be adding that edit this afternoon, code is on a different computer...)...and Its still closing the socket, although the service is no longer being destroyed.  Now I have it running startService in `onStart`, and stopService in `onDestroy`, under an `isFinishing` if block.  I also ran a more specific check by...not closing, but backgrounding the activity by opening something else...the socket is closing during the creation/re-open cycle...which  is not at all where I expected..

Answer (score 1):

'Socket closed' means that *you* closed the socket and then continued to use it. It isn't a 'disconnect'.

You need to put something into that catch block. Never just ignore an exception. You might get a surprise when you see what the exception actually was.

NB `Socket.isConnected()` doesn't tell you anything about the state of the connection: only whether you have ever connected the `Socket.` You have, so it returns true.

Comment: Socket Closed IS the exception, that's what the stack trace is there for, and why I know what it's doing...or rather, not doing.  i dont know what's closing the socket

Comment: You are closing the socket. Nothing in the JDK closes sockets automatically except a connect failure. Possibly you're unaware that closing the input or output stream of a socket closes the other stream and the socket.

Comment: All I'm doing is changing the orientation.  SOMETHING about that, causes a socket, inside a service that was bound to the activity, to be closed.  I never, not even once, call Socket.Close().  This means that something else is closing it at some point in that procedure.  I'm looking for some assistance with what that could be...if anyone has any.

Comment: And no, the service isn't being stopped.  I checked that already.  StopService never runs.  So it doesn't come from there either.